# Windows taskkill not finding titled cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm starting a lot of .bats, in which I execute, for example:

```
title Waterfall-Proxy
```

I do this, to have an easier closing the right cmds when I want to shut them down.
To shut them down, I'm using:

```
taskkill /IM cmd.exe /FI “WINDOWTITLE eq Waterfall-Proxy”
```

However, this doesn't find any cmds with the correct title. When I use tasklist there are no such titled cmds either. 
What is causing this?

Comment: [Your syntax to set the title is wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552368/windows-batch-file-taskkill-if-window-title-contains-text)

Comment: While in no way disagreeing wit @Ramhound, long experience has taught me to reduce the number of things open to what I can reasonably deal with to be easier, faster, and more productive overall.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that multiple filters all get executed and are not combined
to one filter. Meaning that your `taskkill` command will kill *all* `cmd.exe`.

An (untested) adaptation of the
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26552603/165358)
given by Ramhound in a comment above is:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('
    tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh 
    ^| findstr /c:"Waterfall-Proxy"
') do taskkill /pid %%a
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't do anything, it simply opens and closes.

Comment: It *is* untested, so you will need to debug. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

- ***[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)***

```
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %i in =;(` 2^>nul %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe process where "caption='java.exe' and CommandLine Like '%waterfall-1.20-552.jar%'" get processid /format:xml ^| find "VALUE" `);= do %__AppDir__%taskkill.exe /f /pid %~i

:: or... 

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %i in =;(` 2^>nul %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe process where "caption='cmd.exe' and CommandLine Like '%start_proxy.bat%'" get processid /format:xml ^| find "VALUE" `);= do %__AppDir__%taskkill.exe /f /pid %~i
```

---

- ***[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)***

```
@echo off

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in =;(`
     %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe process where "caption='java.exe' and CommandLine Like '%%waterfall-1.20-552.jar%%'" get processid /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `);= do %__AppDir__%taskkill.exe /f /pid %%~i

:: or...

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in =;(`
     2^>nul %__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe process where "caption='cmd.exe' and CommandLine Like '%%start_proxy.bat%%'" get processid /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `);= do %__AppDir__%taskkill.exe /f /pid %%~i
```

Assuming that it refers to ***[Waterfall 1.20](https://papermc.io/downloads/waterfall)***, although this is a `.jar`, I therefore suggest looking for its **PID** in a **Java** process, where the **`Name.jar`** is present in the `execution/command line`, and by hitting, kill the process using the corresponding/pertinent ***`PID number`***

---